# Suggestions on Framework/API to create social graph and cross reference relationships

Tags: frameworks, relationship, social-networking, search-suggestion, social-graph

**Short Question Description**

I have to develop an application for a security company that will store cases of harassment to their clients and cross reference any case with other cases if it detects it is the same person that is attacking them.

These relationships will be used to create a **social graph** of criminals and victims.

Initially I thought about managing it as a Social Network with some CMS or maybe Elastic Search with some frontend JS Framework but I have only experience with PHP and some basic React/Node.js so I wonder if there is something better that let me make the queries live as users fill in the forms.

**Long Question with Use Case Example**

Lets say they have two clients: **ProtectedPerson1** and **ProtectedPerson2**

and there is a case saying **BadGuy1** threatened **PP1** in twitter with the handle **@badguy1**.

Then another agent that does not know anything about this case enters a new case for **PP2**, because someone in facebook is posting private photos of the client.

If they start to put the social information and they type **@badguy1** or **faceboo.com/badguy1** or anything similar the system should ask "is this the same person?" and if the agent selects **Yes** then both records of two separate cases are related to the same "criminal".

In the end the final objective is to gather all precedents possible to take legal action against someone if is necessary.

---

Is there any existing Framework, CMS or API that I can use to manage this relationships and create the desired **suggestions** and **graphs**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation I found that what I really need is a graph database and the one that stands out as the most used one and with better support and integrations is Neo4j (https://neo4j.com) with a front end in React possibly as they offer official driver for javascript.